# "As" means in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The boat was nowhere to be seen. The stake which had held it had also disappeared. Far **as** the eye could reach nothing was visible but water.

I think "As" means "although" here, am I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. "As" does not mean "although". The sentence:

> Far although the eye could see there was nothing but water.

is not grammatical English and is pretty hard to understand.

Defining words such as "as" is notoriously tricky and the definitions are often not too helpful. "As" is a conjunction, an adverb, and a preposition.

"As far as" is a pretty common phrase in English, sometimes shortened to "Far as". In this context, it just sort of intensifies the statement.

(By the way, the usual verb would be "see" not "reach").

Comment: "For the whole distance that it was possible to see, there was nothing but water."